# how can I log to a file with the standard lib "logging" from the ipython qtconsole?

Tags: python, logging, ipython

I noticed that I can't log to a file under ipython the way it is possible from the terminal.

If I run the following code from the console the file aaa.log is created but not when I run it from the ipython qtconsole. (I use python 3.2.3  ipython: 0.13.1)

My suspicion is that ipython's own logging feature is in the way. Is there a way to also also use this "standard" logging with ipython? Outputting the logging messages to the qtconsole seems to work however.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='aaa.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG) 

def my_method():
    logging.debug('This message should go to the log file 2')
    logging.info('So should this')
    logging.warning('And this, too')

if __name__=='__main__':
    my_method()
```

Comment: I found an answer to my question here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691130/how-to-completely-reset-python-stdlib-logging-module-in-an-ipython-session

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup of yours and everything works fine. Are you sure you are searching for the file in the correct directory? You can use the following to check your current directory (the directory where the log file will be written):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
```

Also you can try to specify the full path as `filename="/path/to/aaa.log"`.

Comment: thanks, your answer helped me find the real problem:
It works as it should (with relative as well as absolute paths) but only the first time I run the script. When I edit the filename ('aaa.log') in the script and then rerun it with "run scriptname.py" it doesn't use the changed version, therefore the log file is not created. When I restart the ipythonconsole it works. Is it the same for you or does it work as expected?

Comment: I just meant changing the name to 'aaa2.log' so that a new file is created. However I finally found out that one should not use logging.basicConfig() for interactive sessions.